# Saving Arraylist to Text document seperate lines

Tags: java, android

Trying to save arraylist items to a text file, I kind of have it working but it saves the whole arraylist on one line

I am hoping to save it per line and not have any duplicates or the empty brackets at the start, Any help would be much appreciated. Also if possible to remove the brackets around the text for easier reading into an arraylist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FileOutputStream is more fitting for when your data is already in a byte format. I suggest you use something like a PrintWriter.

```
PrintWriter pw = null;
try {

    File file = new File("file.txt"); //edited
    pw = new PrintWriter(file); //edited
    for(String item: Subreddit_Array_List)
        pw.println(item);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
    pw.close();
}
```

Keep in mind this overwrites what was in the file before rather than appends to it. The output will be formatted like:

```
Cats
Dogs
Birds
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, this does not create a file

Comment: My bad, it's OS specific I believe. Instead of giving the PrintWriter the file path directly, you should create a File object with the file path, and pass the File object to PrintWriter. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the map and save all variables in separate lines.

**Example:**

```
private List<Object> objects;

  private void example() {
    //JDK >= 8
    this.objects.forEach(this::writeInFile);
    //JDK < 8
    for (Object object : this.objects) {
      this.writeInFile(object);
    }
  }

  private void writeInFile(Object object) {
    //your code here
  }
```